# RHEL terminal basic syntax highlighting

Tags: terminal, rhel

I am new to RHEL, so pardon me if this is trivial...

How to get your RHEL terminal to show basic syntax highlighting?

Currently it shows a dumb white screen with a black colored font.

Comment: What do you mean by syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such function is enabled by customizing your shell config files. Depending on the shell you use, it would be .bashrc, .cshrc, .zshrc, etc, in home directory. There are plenty of these on github.com. For example below repo has user customized .bashrc.

https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles